# split byte string into lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I split a byte string into a list of lines?

In python 2 I had:

```
rest = "some\nlines"
for line in rest.split("\n"):
    print line
```

The code above is simplified for the sake of brevity, but now after some regex processing, I have a byte array in `rest` and I need to iterate the lines.

Comment: Do you have `rest = "some\nlines"` or rather `rest = b"some\nlines"` in Python3?

Comment: @Flavius Then try to identify at what point in the process your string becomes a bytes object... then you can improve that point.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

There is no reason to convert to string. Just give `split` bytes parameters. Split strings with strings, bytes with bytes.

```
>>> a = b'asdf\nasdf'
>>> a.split(b'\n')
[b'asdf', b'asdf']
```

Also, since you're splitting on newlines, you could slightly simplify that by using [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.splitlines) (available for both `str` and `bytes`):

```
>>> a = b'asdf\nasdf'
>>> a.splitlines()
[b'asdf', b'asdf']
```

Comment: Clean and easy.. Nevertheless, I see no reason why python does not handle `string` as `byte` automatically when applying it on a `byte` typed variable

Comment: @gies0r Same reason Python doesn't do duck typing in general: It enables sloppy code and forces Python to have a "native" encoding

Answer (score 24):

Decode the bytes into unicode (str) and then use `str.split`:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 19:53:16) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = b'asdf\nasdf'
>>> a.split('\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
>>> a = a.decode()
>>> a.split('\n')
['asdf', 'asdf']
>>>
```

You can also split by `b'\n'`, but I guess you have to work with strings not bytes anyway. So convert all your input data to `str` as soon as possible and work only with unicode in your code and convert it to bytes when needed for output as late as possible.

Answer (score 10):

try this.. .  
`rest = b"some\nlines"`

`rest=rest.decode("utf-8")`  
 then you can do `rest.split("\n")`