# split bytes variable on newline

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

This is an unusual request, and I would appreciate some guidance! :)

I have a python variable, for simplicity we can call it 'output'

When I print output I get the following:

```
b"word1\nword2\nword3\n"
```

I would love it if I could print

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
```

I have tried to split the variable, and feed it to a for loop with zero success.  I am happy to write the output to a file in the OS and use bash to resolve the issue as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [split byte string into lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857856/split-byte-string-into-lines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to do this (see the [`string.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) function for more details)...

```
for word in output.decode('utf-8').split('\n'):
    print word
```

And you don't need to print word - you can do anything you want with it. This loop will iterate over every line in `output`.

Comment: Calling split with no args will split on more than just `\n` (which may or may not matter here)

Comment: If `\n` is being printed, that means that the actual string includes `\\n`.

Comment: @jeff_h is there any reason you're using bytes instead of a string?

Comment: I have tried splitting before I get the error:

    for i in output.split('\n'):
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: I am using the variable name output, this is how it is created:

output = ssh_stderr.read() + ssh_stdout.read()

Comment: The data that forms the variable is coming through paramiko

Comment: @jeff_h Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string If you first decode the data into a string before doing what I (or any other answer) said, it should work.

Comment: @stanpines testing that idea now with print(output.decode("utf-8"))

Comment: @stanpines you were correct, if you add it as an answer I can mark it as resolved :)

Comment: @jeff_h how's that? :)

Comment: @stanpines You don't need the split :)

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you are using Python 3 and invoking the equivalent of

```
>>> print(b"foo\nbar\nbaz")
b'foo\nbar\nbaz'
```

This is `str(bytes)` in action: the (Unicode) string representation of a byte string. By decoding it first you get something that Python 3 will print more elegantly.

```
>>> print(b"foo\nbar\nbaz".decode('utf-8'))
foo
bar
baz
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Python 3. You have a bytes string (bytes), different from a unicode string (str).

```
bstring = b"word1\nword2\nword3\nword4"
```

The newline `'\n'` is the same as `u'\n'` (unicode string) and different from `b'\n'`.
If you are interested simply in the splitting you can use `b'\n'` as separator:

```
for w in bstring.split(b'\n'):
    print(w)
```

This will print bytes strings `b'word1'`, ...
If you want regular strings you have to decode before or after the splitting like shown in the other solutions:

```
for w in bstring.decode().split('\n'):
    print(w)
```

This uses your default encoding (normally utf-8), if you want a different one you can pass it as argument to `decode()`. You can find more in the [Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)

Answer (score 2):

To me it sounds like your string has *escaped* newlines.  `str.split` won't help you here, nor `str.splitlines`.  You need to decode the escapes:

```
>>> print s
word1\nword2\nwored3\n
>>> print s.decode('string-escape')
word1
word2
wored3
```

Comment: Interesting, so I should try: print(output.decode('\\n')) ? :)

Answer (score -1):

```
output = b"word1\nword2\nword3\nword4\n"
for w in output.split():
    print(w)
```