# Python: Splitting text/xml;charset=UTF-8

Tags: python, html, dictionary, utf-8

I made a request to an api and it returned

```
b"001-1001\thazraja\t122.9668944300\t43.1858693000\t[YES]\t1456529273000\t2437.0000000000\n001-1002\tZ8s14\t122.9671153000\t43.1860681800\t[NO]\t1456529275000\t2462.0000000000\n..."
```

It goes on like that for some time, starting again at the carriage return "\n". It always has 7 items before it starts again.

`print(response.headers["content-type"])` returns

`text/xml;charset=UTF-8`

How would I access "001-1001" as well as "thajraza", etc? I'm not sure what the name is of the type of thing the api returned? Is it a list? A dictionary? Something else?

Comment: Why would you want to parse a dictionary? What is even the meaning thereof? Also, what exactly are you referring to with "this type of return"?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I dont understand what the api returned. I see that it is bytes as indicated by the "b" and I see tabs and carriage returns, I'm just looking for a what to access "001-1001" as well as "thazraja", etc.

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: Ah. Two things: It claims to be XML (`text/xml`), which seems to be a lie. Rather, this seems like a sequence of strings separated by tabs. Now, to get from "raw" bytes to a string, use the `decode()` method. This claims to be UTF-8 (`charset=UTF-8`), but that might be wrong, too, but that will only show if you have characters outside of ASCII. With that string, proceed as with the answer you found below and/or the CSV module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I get it... with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15095537/5893677).

```
>>> a = b'asdf\nasdf'
>>> a.split(b'\n')
[b'asdf', b'asdf']
```

I can split it at the tabs and carriage return. I was looking for an explanation. Sometimes it's hard searching for things when you don't know the appropriate terminology.

Comment: You seem to have CSV data (only that it is tab-separated, not comma-separated, which is not important). Try using the `csv` module for that.